# What's the purpose of Auth0 SSO Integrations?

Tags: auth0

Under the Auth0 dashboard, there is an option *SSO Integrations* with a number of listed applications such as Active Directory RMS, SharePoint and so on.

What does this exactly do? I'm trying to find some documentation around this.

Answer (score 2):

The SSO Integrations provides you a packaged experience so that you can quickly configure any of the listed applications to use Auth0 for authentication.

This does not mean that you cannot integrate applications not mentioned in the list; it just means that those, possibly due to popularity, got special treatment.

For an example on integrating with Slack, check this tutorial ([Integrate Auth0 with Slack](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/integrating-with-slack)).

> You can configure Slack to login with Auth0. That way, users would be able to login with any of the identity providers supported by Auth0, such as Active Directory, LDAP, Google Apps, Facebook, Google, Twitter, and so on.

Comment: Agree entirely with the answer. To add - an important distinction here is that the SSO Integrations are using Auth0 as the Identity Provider (performing the identity credentials verification). This differs from say the Social and Enterprise Connections in which Auth0 acts as a Service Provider that delegates IAM to the underlying Identity Provider (in this example say Google, Facebook or an Enterprise Active Directory)